# Proof $a+a = 0$ by given $a\times a = a$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ring-theory, proof-explanation

I'm wondering how I can proof that for the following Ring $(R; +,-,0,\times,1)$ with $a \times a = a$ that $a + a = 0$.

How can I proof that? I just know about the lemma:

(i) $0(a) = a(0) = 0$

(ii) $(−a)b = −(ab)$

(iii) $(−a)(−b) = ab$

Many thanks in advance!!!

Kind regards

Comment: Well, in the integers we have $1\times 1 =1$ but $1+1\neq 0$.  Did you omit some assumption about $R$?

Comment: Are you claiming that $0$ and $1$ are the only elements?  Can you prove that $0 + 0 = 0$ and $1+1= 0$?

Comment: What does notation $(R;+,-,0,\times, 1)$ mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This homework usually assumes that $a^2=a$ holds for **all** elements $a$. Then we have
$$(a+a) = (a+a)^2 = a^2+2a^2+a^2= a+a+a+a \Rightarrow a+a = 0 .$$

Possible duplicte of

[Let R be a ring such that $a^2 = a$ , $\forall a$ $\in R$ . Prove that R is commutative.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1634787/let-r-be-a-ring-such-that-a2-a-forall-a-in-r-prove-that-r-is-comm)

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Now I know how I should have looked at the exercise...

Comment: Could you maybe explain me the steps from: $a^2$+2$a^2$+$a^2$ =a+a+a+a⇒a+a=0.

Comment: Do it termwise. First summand is $a^2=a$. Second term is $2a^2=2a=a+a$, etc.